# php код для получения данных формы

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, form

Нужна помощь с написанием php для сервера, так как в php совсем не разбираюсь. Есть форма где только одно поле а именно *email* которое нужно отправить на сервер. И получить с сервера ответ(успех\ошибка)

```
<form method="post" class='collectForm'>
    <h3>SUBSCRIBE TO NEWS</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
    <input type="email" name='email' placeholder="You e-mail">
    <input type="submit" name='button' class="-btnType" value='SEND'>
</form>
```

Нужно отправить это значение на сервер с помощью **ajax**, написал такой скрипт:

```
$('.collectForm').submit(function(e){
    var form = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        type: form.attr('method'),
        url: 'ajax_ser.php',
        data: form.serialize()
    }).done(function(){
        alert('succes')
    }).fail(function(){
        console.log('fail')
    })
});
```

По скрипту тоже вопросы:

1. **action** и **method** лучше задавать в скрипте или в html?
2. Подходит ли этот скрипт для отправки формы?
3. Стоит ли использовать метод **post** для отправки *email* на сервер?

Comment: Подскажите, почему выбрали метод отправки через `ajax`? Почему не отправляете данные на сервер через `php`?

Comment: @Denis640Kb просто изучаю ajax. Если правильно понял вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML:

```
<form method="post" class='collectForm' action='/path/to/script.php'>
    <h3>SUBSCRIBE TO NEWS</h3>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. </p>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Your e-mail">
    <input type="submit" name="send" class="-btnType" value='SEND'>
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".collectForm").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            method: $(this).attr('method'),
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data) {
                alert("Запрос доставлен. Вернулся ответ: "+data);
            },
            error: function(xhr,status) {
                alert("Ошибка: "+status);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if(!isset($_POST['email'])) die("Hacking attempt");
  $email = htmlspecialchars($_POST['email']);
  // делаем что-то с переменной $email
  echo "Успех";
?>
```

Касательно вопросов:

1. Если отправляете данные без использования AJAX, то необходимо задавать method и action в атрибутах формы. Если используете AJAX, то method и action задаются непосредственно в скрипте (но action в нём называется url). Можно использовать AJAX, но при этом задавать method и action в атрибутах формы, после чего цеплять их в скрипте. Это позволит не лезть внутрь скрипта, если будет необходимо что-то поменять.
2. Подходит.
3. POST-запрос в данном случае более уместен.

Comment: Почему форма не нужна? Ведь намного удобнее при событии отправки формы `$("#idForm").submit(function(e) {` сериализовать данные и отправить их безо всяких комбинаций `data: form.serialize()` вроде выше описанных `'email='+$("#email").val()`

Comment: @Alpha спасибо, поправил.

Comment: @Dmitry работает, но пропущенные вроде как **{}**,  `$.ajax({...})` да?

Comment: @Cobret да, прошу прощения, по запарке упустил.